# SQL Assistance needed for a not so simple query

Tags: sql

I have a database with a customer table and a loan table.  The customer table has about 11,000 records.  The loan table has the customer account numbers for each loan entry and specific codes for what type of loan product was taken.  However, as you can see, not every customer has taken a loan out, so that table has fewer records than the customer table.  I need to find a way to gather the customers that meet certain criteria from customers (are they active for example), then possibly join (*maybe*) to the loan table and return the codes for a specific loan.  However, I'd still want the customers from the customers table who didn't take loans included in the record set.

So, all the customers who are active and if there is data for that customer in the loan table to return that in the recordset.

I'm just unsure how to get it done, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific in what you try to do?
however left join seems to be the answer

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  for your next questions

Comment: Start with understanding joins:  https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ covers the basics, `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL OUTER`, `CROSS JOIN`.  Then you can get into more complex concepts of `OUTER APPLY` and `CROSS APPLY`.  For those knowledgeable in SQL this is pretty simple.  you just have to understand the nature of joins.  Also include (tag) which database you're using.  mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Postgresql all have different synax which can change how people respond.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do LEFT JOIN. Something like :

```
SELECT c.* , l.loan_code
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN loans l
    ON c.customer_id = l.customer_id
WHERE c.is_active is true
...
```

Comment: Since the Question appears to begin with not understanding joins, it would be nice to include why this would work.  Like "A left join in this table order will return all records from customers and only those records which match from loans.  Then, the where clause is applied and only active customers are returned showing all the customer details; but no loan details... (you may want to do l.* too so all the loan details are shown if any exist)